# Using rubyonrail code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rubyonrail code for getting value of username and password in post form method but i am not getting this value please can you tell me what is wroong in this code

File Name : home/index.html.erb

```
<p><label for="login">Login:</label> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
  <%= text_field "login", "text1", "size" => 20 %> 
</p>

<p>
  <label for="password">Password:</label> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <%= text_field "password", "text2", "size" => 20 %>
</p>
  <%= button_to "Submit", home_index_path, method =>:post%>
```

Controller/homecontroller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @data = param:[text1]
    end     

    def new
    end

    def create
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a form tag in there somewhere - the rails way is to include a form_tag helper at the start of the form:

```
<%=form_tag(home_index_path, method =>:post%>
 <p><label for="login">Login:</label> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <%= text_field_tag "login", "text1", "size" => 20 %> 
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="password">Password:</label> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <%= text_field_tag "password", "text2", "size" => 20 %>
    </p>
<%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
```

You should then be able to get your username and password in the controller using params[:login] and params[:password].  Note that I have also changed "text_field" to "text_field_tag" and "submit" to "submit_tag."  You can read more about these helpers at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html

Comment: And I agree with bbozo that you should not roll your own authentication solution but look at devise or authlogic instead.  Easier and more secure.

Answer (score 0):

See http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

or https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

or https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic

it should get you off your feet.

Alternatively, look for rails tutorials on the web, most of them handle authentication

Answer (score 0):

Change code as below and it would work.

HTML Page

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "home", action: "index"}, method: "get") do %>
<%= label_tag(:text1, "Enter Username :") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:text1, nil, placeholder: 'Enter text') %>
<%= label_tag(:text2, "Enter Password :") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:text2, nil, placeholder: 'Enter Password') %>
<%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @data = params[:text1]
    end     

  def new
  end

  def create
  end

end
```